# Java: Caught exception is immediately rethrown? What's the problem?

Tags: java, exception

I have the following Java code (that I thought was OK) but the IDE is warning me that "IOExcpetion e is immediately rethrown."

I'm new to exception handling in Java, and I wasn't aware there was anything wrong with doing that.

From what I'm reading, it looks like my other options is to simply delete the catch block and replace it with a finally block... but then it warns that the finally block is empty.

I don't have any ideas on what I should do differently.

```
private InputStream getFlutterAssetAsInputStream(String fromAsset) throws IOException {
    String assetPath = binding
            .getFlutterAssets()
            .getAssetFilePathBySubpath(fromAsset, PACKAGE_NAME);

    try {
      return binding.getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(assetPath);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw e;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
try {
  return binding.getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(assetPath);
} 
catch (IOException e) {
  throw e;
}
```

is functionally equivalent to this:

```
  return binding.getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(assetPath);
```

Your IDE is telling you that your try-catch is pointless. It does nothing.

So what do you want to do?

1. Pass the exception on to your caller?  In which case get rid of the try-catch
2. Signal a different exception on to the caller - maybe one with a more appropriate error message for the specific circumstances?  Then make and throw a new exception object with a better error message.
3. Do something to handle the situation - at the very least, maybe display an error message?  Log the event to enable debugging? Then write code in the catch-block to do that. And then you have to decide what happens next.

Fundamentally, this is a design issue. IO errors happen. So how does this method that you're writing want to handle IO errors?